# Can I use audio containing Canadian ATC/broadcast radio transmissions in a YouTube video?

Tags: radio-communications, canada

I often record my flight training without audio and post some of it to YouTube. I would like to add in audio recording of what I hear and say over the radio as well, but my ground school suggested that it was illegal to make radio transmissions public. On the other hand, I see youtube videos all the time that do include ATC voice traffic.

Can someone clarify for me if it is permissible to record and make public radio transmissions recorded during my own flights?

If it makes any difference, my videos are not/will not be monetized and and my flight training takes place in Canada.

EDIT: finally remembered my source, which is the radio operator restricted certificate study guide, which says:

Radio operators and all persons who become acquainted with radiocommunications are bound to
preserve the privacy of those communications. In accordance with subsection 9(2) of the
Radiocommunication Act, no person shall divulge the contents, or the existence, of communications
transmitted, received or intercepted by a radio station, except as permitted by the addressee of the
message or his/her accredited agent, or to authorized officials of the Government of Canada, officers of
the court or an operator of a telecommunications system as is necessary to forward or deliver the
communication. These restrictions do not apply to a message of distress, urgency, safety or to messages
addressed to “ALL STATIONS” (i.e. weather reports, storm warnings, etc.).
As outlined in section 9.1 of the Act, any person who violates the privacy of communications is liable,
on summary conviction, in the case of an individual, to a fine not exceeding twenty-five thousand dollars
or to imprisonment for a term not exceeding one year, or to both, or, in the case of a person other than an
individual, on summary conviction, to a fine not exceeding seventy-five thousand dollars. https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/smt-gst.nsf/eng/sf01397.html

It sounds like I am able to post radio communications for which I am the addressee (and presumably addressor)

Comment: I would not hesitate to do that.  But, this is just a comment, not a real answer.

Comment: Ask them to point you to their source. In the USA that's nonsense, but I don't know about Canadian law.  Also, realize that if you did anything that could get you or your instructor in trouble, even without realizing it at the time, a posted video is pretty clear evidence of what happened.  Time can be correlated to ATC tapes.  At a minimum, might want to get your instructor to consent, since it's his ticket on the line if somebody makes a stink about something & an investigator agrees that it's an issue.

Comment: @RalphJ fair point, I will do that. Mostly I had planned on posting solo video though.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here you might consider asking on [law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/). Although there's [at least one prominent example](https://flightchops.com/about-me/) that shows this is completely legal in Canada.

Comment: You can't do this in the UK, but it looks like you can in Canada. [LiveATC even has Canadian channels](https://www.liveatc.net/feedindex.php?type=canada).

Comment: Until you get more information, you should assume this is not allowed, as in many countries this won't be allowed. Some years ago, and possibly still today, just *listening* to ATC wasn't permitted in the UK, unless you were using ATC services. US have another view on privacy (disclosed data can be used by anyone), and are not the predominant model in this area.

Comment: Sounds like this might be a question for law.SE after all

Comment: If your ground school suggested you not to do it, then do not.

You're better off losing a few views than losing your license.

Comment: I don't see how there is any reasonable expectation of privacy with radio broadcast but lawmakers have been known to get absurd notions in their heads. Canada law tends to settle somewhere between the UK and USA in many areas. In the USA recording private comms generally requires consent, but speaking in a manner that can be readily overheard by passive non-participants is not considered private. An office with door closed, telephone call, letter in an envelope, encrypted radio all considered private. Conversation open to a common-use hall at work or non-encrypted radio broadcast are public.

Comment: @MaxPower that is certainly the most reasonable way to approach it, but as you say, reasonable doesn't always matter legally

Comment: @KBriggs "reasonable expectation" is actually legal terminology, I didn't mean it in the informal manner.

Comment: @MaxPower good to know

Comment: Thanks for mentioning your edits, and this was a great question to answer especially for a Canadian citizen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In countries where it is illegal to listen to ATC chatter like the UK, it is also illegal to post it, and you can see this on LiveATC, where you can easily listen to YKZ, YYZ, YVR, YTZ, and YHZ, etc. in Canada, but you can't listen to UK airport feeds or sectors for example LHR, LGW and MAN.

So assuming that liveatc is not an illegal orginization, (we know that for sure because literally the #1 thing that comes up when you search on google atc, liveatc comes up. And if it was illegal, the RCMP would have taken down liveatc at least in canada years ago!) we can say that no, posting atc chatter online is not illegal in Canada.

Comment: Is it possible those Canadian transmissions are being recorded and posted by receivers on the United States side of the border, and would that not make the legal ssue much different? Also I know Canadian ATC controls some low altitude sectors of US airspace in NW Washington, due to radar coverage I presume, domestic US flights that never cross the border.

Comment: @Max Power: That's like saying the irish people on the other side could be recording UK transmissions or like saying if a foreigner came in and didn't pay taxes it would be legal. Plus, if it was US citizens who were recording the transmissions, then how would we be able to get transmissions from CYHZ? I highly doubt that US frequency scanners would be in range at that point.

Answer (score 1):

The Legal answer is no

> Prohibition
>
> (1.1) Except as prescribed, no person shall make use of or divulge a radio-based telephone communication
>
> (a) if the originator of the communication or the person intended by the originator of the communication to receive it was in Canada
> when the communication was made; and
>
> (b) unless the originator, or the person intended by the originator to receive the communication consents to the use or
> divulgence.
>
> Marginal note:Idem
>
> (2) Except as prescribed, no person shall intercept and make use of, or intercept and divulge, any radiocommunication, except as
> permitted by the originator of the communication or the person
> intended by the originator of the communication to receive it.
>
> Marginal note:Exceptions
>
> (3) Subsection (2) does not apply in respect of radiocommunication that consists of broadcasting, a subscription programming signal or a
> network feed.
>
> 1989, c. 17, s. 61991, c. 11, s. 831993, c. 40, s. 24

https://laws.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/r-2/fulltext.html

In reality, if you are posting simple routine communications Its unlikely any inspector would bother tracking you down, and worst case you would probably get a "don't do it again" letter, an alternative would be to show your calls, then edit out the response.

Edit, upon re-reading, it looks like you may be able to show your communications with ATC, but only yours, "unless the originator, or the person intended by the originator to receive the communication"

Also yes, Live ATC is not really aloud to post radio traffic [they may be legal to rebroadcast in real time], I doubt anyone cares enough to enforce the rules.